# Check/Uncheck of check box using Robot framework and swing libraries

Tags: swing, robotframework

In my system I have a routing table which I control from GUI. To delete a route/s I need to do check a check box (say if I consider the routing table in the form of cells, then say row 1 column 8 till row 5 column 8 I have that check box).

How to do that check/uncheck using robot framework and swing libraries?

```
1   2   3   4   
2
3
```

Considering this to be the format of routing table (3 rows 4 columns), I have the check in say 4th column.

Keyword that I have written to get the contents of row/column:

```
***keyword***
Route    
     Select Main Window
     Push Toggle BUtton   ShowIpViewAction
     Select Tab   8    
     #List components in context
     ${columns}=    Get Table Column Count     IpRoutingStaticRoutesTable
     ${rows}=    Get Table Row Count    IpRoutingStaticRoutesTable
     ${row_value}=   Get Table Cell Value    IpRoutingStaticRoutesTable  2   2
```

Comment: The `Robot` can only click on a certain point on-screen.  I don't think it is the right tool for this job (nor is Java generally).

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to use robot?Make multidim array of checkboxes and .setSelected(true/false); with bunch of if and while statements. You will have to go thru all of them and i woud not use any grouping in this case.I woud provide some code bud as i can see you didnt show anything yet to me so try something and come back.

Comment: Tomas,Yes i have to use Robot Framework for this thing as it is the framework that we use for automating our test cases involving the GUI.

Comment: I agree that Robot does not seem to be the right approach here. But in general, it is at least theoretically possible to obtain the bounds of any component on the screen. So at least theoretically, you could work your way from the main JFrame through the component tree down to the checkboxes, obtain their bounds in the screen, and use the robot to issue a click on them. You could. Although probably, you shouldn't.

Comment: Tip:  Add @Marco13 (or whoever - the `@` is important) to *notify them* of a new comment.  Now that is out of the way, I think I made a wrong edit to your question.  I *removed* the [tag:robot-framework] tag thinking you actually meant the [`java.awt.Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class of the JSE.  Do you actually mean the app. **uses** the [Python based Robot Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/robotframework)?

Comment: @Andrew..Yes.Actually i am trying to automate my operations on the GUI using the python based Robot Framework. For reading the Tabs and panes i am using the Jspy. But for the table structure Jspy is not giving the Name or context which i can use.

Comment: I am trying to write a keyword for this..but not able to proceed any further.